# 301 htaccess redirect for WordPress tag

Tags: htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect

I need a 301 redirect for tag pages that have been created, for example:

`http://www.mydomain.co.uk/tag/endovenous-laser/page/14/?m&pgd=10`

It might look something like this I guess, but this did not work:

```
RewriteRule^tag/endovenous-laser/(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.co.uk/treatments/endovenous-laser-ablation-evla/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the method I use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tag/endovenous-laser/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.mydomain.co.uk/treatments/endovenous-laser-ablation-evla/ [R=301,L]
```

Short of a typo, this should work.